# Excel : worksheet update event not caught

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have two workbooks opened in the same Excel, in the first one named test1, a list of 5 names with a number to the right, in the second one the same 5 names and this formula:

```
=([test1.xlsx]Sheet1!$C$5)
```

to the right. So when I update the numbers in the first worksheet they are automatically updated in the second one.
Now I added a piece of VBA code in the second Worksheet_Change event. The event fires when I change a number in the second worksheet but when the updates comes from the first one it doesn't work!!  Any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Worksheet_Calculate` or `Workbook_SheetCalculate` events

Comment: Hi Paul, Just tried it, works like a charm!!  Thank You